# iPhone 7 flashing

Tags: ios, iphone

During an update of my iPhone through iTunes, an error message appears on my computer screen and since my iPhone 7 is just flashing slowly from black to white with the Apple logo. I tried everything but not avail, it's just flashing and flashing.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your iPhone in DFU mode and restore it.

1. **Plug in** your iPhone to your Mac or Windows PC.
2. Make sure **iTunes** is running.
3. **Turn Off** your iPhone if it isn't already.
4. Press and hold down the **On/Off** button of the device for 3 seconds. Swipe the slide to power off slider to the right.
5. Press and hold down the **On/Off** button on your device for 3 seconds.
6. Press and hold down the **Home** button on the front of your device while still holding down the **On/Off** button.
7. Keep holding **both** buttons down for 10 seconds. (If you see the Apple logo, you've held them too long and will need to start again.)
8. Let go of the **On/Off** Button but keep holding the Home button for about 5 seconds. (If you see the "Plug into iTunes" screen, then you've held it too long and will need to start again.)
9. If the screen stays black, that's it! Your iPhone should now be in DFU mode.

At this point, iTunes should show you an alert saying it's detected your iPhone and will allow it to be restored.